# Playframework scala slick database connections and aws

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, playframework

I have a problem with my database connections. Whenever my project runs a db.run from any of my microservices it creates a new connection to my db. I have a play-scala-slick project and I'm using Amazon Web Services (AWS).
Do I have to manually open and close connections e.g. for every query from any of my microservices or is there a clean, proper, smooth way to handle my connections? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution is to steh the timeout variables in aws rds.

First you have to set up a Parameter Group

```
set global wait_timeout=3;
set global interactive_timeout=3;
```